# Bulk insert data in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Based on an existing relational table I want to create a graph. The table has the following two columns ItemId and ParentItemId. The ParentItemId can be null. The graph will consist in the items and the “child” relation between parent and child. To do that I used the following code:

```
    public class ItemRecord
    {
        public int ItemId;
        public int? ParentItemId;
    }

    public class ItemNode
    {
        public int ItemId;            
    }

    public void BuildGraph(IEnumerable<ItemRecord> data)
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "user", "pass");
        graphClient.Connect();

        var tran = graphClient.BeginTransaction();
        var nodes = data.Select(item => new ItemNode {ItemId = item.ItemId});

        try
        {
            //creates the nodes in a single operation
            graphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(n:Item {nodes})")
            .WithParam("nodes", nodes)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

            ///creates the relations
            foreach (var nodeItem in data)
            {
                if (!nodeItem.ParentItemId.HasValue)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                graphClient.Cypher
                    .Match("(source:Item)", "(destination:Item)")
                    .Where((ItemNode source) => source.ItemId == nodeItem.ParentItemId.Value)
                    .AndWhere((ItemNode destination) => destination.ItemId == nodeItem.ItemId)
                    .Create("source-[:Parent]->destination")
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
            }
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            tran.Rollback();
        }                        
    }
```

First I create the nodes and then the relations between them. This approach is quite slow. For 1000 items it takes approx. 10 seconds. The problem is the fact I am calling the neo4j server for each relation. Is there a way to create the graph in a single statement? How can I improve the perfomance?

Comment: There should be a way in neo4jclient to batch statements into one tx (which can span up to 50000 updates)

Comment: Did you create an index on :Item(ItemId) ? so that those nodes are found quickly?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; - [import tool example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-basic-example.html)

You can use [import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html), that is provided by Neo4j server. It is capable to import a lot of data very quickly.

Tool accepts CSV files on input. So, what you should do is:

1) Write script (or something similar) that will process all your data into CSV files and persists them onto disk.
2) Use import tool and import prepared CSV files into database.

Note: indexes are not created during this process. They should be added later using standard Neo4j capabilities.

---

Example:

**nodes.csv**

```
ItemId:ID,:LABEL,value
item1,Item,"some"
item2,Item,"other"
item3,Item,"another"
```

**relationships.csv**

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
item1,item2,Parent
item1,item3,Parent
```

And command:

```
neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes nodes.csv --relationships relationships.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UNWIND`?

I have the following, which creates 100,000 nodes in roughly 4 seconds (or 1,000 nodes in ~300ms). Obviously I've had to 'fake' up some `ItemRecord` instances, so it may not be exactly the same - and you **NEED** to have an index on your `ItemId` property.

The following code should just be a copy / replace in your current method:

```
public void BuildGraph(IEnumerable<ItemRecord> data)
{
    var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "user", "pass");
    graphClient.Connect();

    //Create the Index.
    graphClient.Create("INDEX ON :Item(ItemId)").ExecuteWithoutResults();

    var tran = graphClient.BeginTransaction();
    var nodes = data.Select(item => new ItemNode {ItemId = item.ItemId});

    try
    {
        //creates the nodes in a single operation
        graphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(n:Item {nodes})")
            .WithParam("nodes", nodes)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        var nodesWithParents = data.Where(n => n.ParentItemId.HasValue);

        //creates the relations
        graphClient.Cypher
            .Unwind(nodesWithParents, "node")
            .Match("(source:Item {ItemId: node.ItemId}),(destination:Item {ItemId : node.ParentItemId})")
            .Create("source-[:Parent]->destination")
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        tran.Rollback();
    }                        
}
```